# Масштабирование изображения

Tags: php

Не знаю, как отмасштабировать изображение. Необходимо отмасштабировать изображение и записать результат в переменную. Я искал готовые скрипты, но то что нашел, не смог самостоятельно понять. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример скрипта с комментариями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/):

```
$resized = $image->resize(100, 100);
```

Особо комментировать тут нечего. :)

Comment: Проще при помощи штатного [imagemagick](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/imagick.scaleimage.php).

Answer (score 2):

С помощью gdlib.

```
<?
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg'); // сообщаем браузеру, что результат работы скрипта это изображение
$fname='test.jpg'; // некий файл на сервере
list($width, $height)=getimagesize($fname); // получаем в $width и $height высоту и ширину картинки
$img=imagecreatefromjpeg($fname); // загружаем изображение из файла
$newwidth=(int) $width/2; // уменьшаем ширину в 2 раза
$newheight=(int) $height/2; // уменьшаем высоту в 2 раза
$newimg=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight); //создаем новое пустое изображение в которое поместим уменьшенный оригинал
imagecopyresized($newimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0,  $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height); // собственно само масштабирование
imagejpeg($newimg); // отдаем картинку браузеру
?>
```